# How can I get VS Code to use a local installation of .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-code, windows-7-x64, .net-core-3.1

My work PC is a Windows 7 machine with Visual Studio 2017 and .NET Core 2.1 SDK. I do not have local admin rights.

I would like to develop an app in .NET Core 3.1 and installed the SDK into my local `AppData` folder using the Powershell [install script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-install-script).

I also installed VS Code as that also doesn't need admin rights.

However, I am unable to debug my app because VS Code always uses the global .NET Core 2.1 SDK which fails of course. How can I force it to use the local 3.1 SDK?

I have tried setting the `PATH` in the integrated terminal as well as the `DOTNET_ROOT` environment variable as mentioned in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet#environment-variables but no luck.

Note, I *am* able to execute `dotnet new` and `dotnet build` etc. from the integrated terminal and those commands *do* use the 3.1 SDK.

Would appreciate any help, thanks.

**Update:** I have noticed that instead of just suffixing `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\dotnet` to the end of the Path, if I completely rewite it, removing `C:\Program Files\dotnet`, then VS Code stops complaining about unresolved references and the red underlines disappear.

This allows me to `restore` and `build`, but I am still unable to debug. Thus it looks like the problem is with the OmniSharp extension as it's always looking in `Program Files` for SDKs.